# 64bits OS can run on Hyper-V?

Tags: hyper-v, 64-bit

I can't install Windows Server 2008 R2 X64 edition on Windows Server 2008 Hyper-V.
I would like to know X64 version can run on Hyper-V or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It should work. What does "can't install" mean?

Answer (score 2):

**If you already have the Hyper-V Role installed and are having trouble in installing Windows 2008 R2, then try using another ISO image or provide the error message you are getting.**

windows 2008 R2 is a 64 Bit ONLY Operating System

If you are running windows 2008, make sure your host operating system is 64BIT and that Hyper-V is configured.

A good thing would be to update your server to the latest service pack (if you have a x64 box and OS).

then try to install again.

Comment: Indeed, under Hyper-V you need a 64bit host to run a 64bit VM.

Comment: After installed update from windows update, i cant start Virtual Machine.
When i check Hyper-V Virtual Network Manager, all my virtual adapter are gone. How can i do?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a list of the supported guests: [Virtualization with Hyper-V: Supported Guest Operating Systems](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/hyperv-supported-guest-os.aspx)